# Send an email to an entire subgroup

Tags: wordpress, civimail

I want to send an email to an entire subcategory of individuals (WordPress, civiCRM 5.52) but the Recipients line only accepts GROUPS.

Do I have to assign a group to this subcategory just to send an email?

Comment: Tom, what do you mean by 'subcategory'? do you mean 'contact sub-type' - if so why not just make a Smart Group based on that criteria - and yes in general CiviMail needs a Group for the mailing target.

Comment: Yes, I meant 'contact sub-type' and Yes, I now realize I must designate a group. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You an also start a mailing from the Advanced Search screen. There is some information here: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/mass-mailings-using-civimail/#the-mailing-set-up-screens

But basically, if you run an advanced search for contacts, one of the options in the Action menu is **Email - schedule/send via CiviMail**

[image]